# Java - Drawing a buffered image into printable vs drawing directly into printable produces fuzzy results

Tags: java, printing

I am designing a Java program for printing some labels on an A4 sheet. I would like to create the labels in a separate class which returns a BufferedImage, then pass a collection of BufferedImages to another class that implements the Printable interface, which will then arrange them on the page and print them.

I can do all this, but am finding when drawing the BufferedImage into the printable, the finer elements, particularly text, are a bit fuzzy. If I draw directly into the graphics object provided by the Printable, then the results are much better, but this is inconvenient for the structure of the program.

I have tried setting the antialiasing hints for text and graphics, and also tried drawing double size image and then scaling it down when drawing into the Printable, but this produces worse results.

Below is a test program I wrote to illustrate the differences. On the output the text is clearly fuzzier when I use a BufferedImage of the same size as the square drawn into the Printable, and again when using a larger BufferedImage and scaled down.

```java
    package printerresolutiontest;

    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.awt.RenderingHints;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
    import java.awt.print.Paper;
    import java.awt.print.Printable;
    import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
    import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;

    public class PrinterResolutionTest implements Printable {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws PrinterException {

            PrinterResolutionTest printrestest = new PrinterResolutionTest();

            PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

            PageFormat pf = pj.defaultPage();
            Paper paper = pf.getPaper();
            paper.setImageableArea(0*72, 0*72, 8.3*72, 11.7*72);
            pf.setPaper(paper);
            pj.setPrintable(printrestest, pf);

            Boolean PRINT_DIALOG_OK = pj.printDialog();
            if (PRINT_DIALOG_OK) {
                pj.print();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
            BufferedImage img1 = new BufferedImage(144, 144, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            BufferedImage img2 = new BufferedImage(72, 72, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

            Graphics2D g2d_bigbuf = img1.createGraphics();
            Graphics2D g2d_buf = img2.createGraphics();            

            if (pageIndex > 0) {
                return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            }

            /*************************
             * Draw directly into the Printable graphics object
             */

            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.fillRect(200, 200, 72, 72);
            g2d.setColor(Color.black);
            g2d.drawString("test", 202, (72/2)+202);

            /*************************
             * Draw the same features
             * into a BufferedImage
             */

            g2d_buf.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d_buf.fillRect(0, 0, 72, 72);
            g2d_buf.setColor(Color.black);
            g2d_buf.drawString("test", 0, 72/2);

            /*************************
             * Draw a double sized square and 
             * increase font size accordingly
             */

            g2d_bigbuf.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d_bigbuf.fillRect(0, 0, 144, 144);
            g2d_bigbuf.setColor(Color.black);
            Font currentfont = g2d_bigbuf.getFont();
            Font newfont = currentfont.deriveFont(currentfont.getSize() * 2F);
            g2d_bigbuf.setFont(newfont);
            g2d_bigbuf.drawString("test", 0, 144/2);

            // Draw the regular sided BufferedImage
            g2d.drawImage(img2, 300, 200, null);
            // Draw the larger BufferedImage and scale down by half
            g2d.drawImage(img1.getScaledInstance(72, 72, Image.SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING), 400, 200, null);

            return PAGE_EXISTS;
        }

    }
```

[BufferedImage test PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DIvc.png)
Here is a test screen capture from a file I printed to PDF as an example of the difference. Ideally I would like to get the same image quality using the BufferedImage as I do when drawing directly into the Printable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screens and printers are very different media. On a screen you typically have a low resolution of about 72 to 92 dpi (pixels per inch). Each pixels can have a huge number of colors (24m or more). On a printer you usually have a high resolution (up to 2540 dpi), but only between 2 (b/w) and 6 colors. In order to create intermediate colors, the printer will you a rasterization technique, e.g. [halftone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halftone).

The way you're creating the *BufferedImage*, you're heavily biased towards screen output: low resolution, use of intermediate colors for anti-aliasing etc. The result will be poor. Furthermore, the intention of your output is lost. The printer driver only sees a pixelmap. It doesn't know if and where text is and cannot optimize the output for it.

In order to improve the quality, you have mainly two options:

- If you only print lines and text and only use the colors that printer can create without mixing colors, you can create a *BufferedImage* that exactly matches the printer resolution and colors. That should give you a decent quality.
- Otherwise, draw directly to the *Printable*. Then the intentions of your output operations are retained and the print driver can produce optimal quality. I'm sure with a bit a thought you can refactor your code such that you still have a very maintainable structure.